# Toggle class if input is empty or contains value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a `disabled` class to an input if the value of the input is empty and remove it if the input has content value. Here is my current take on this that doesn't work:

```
if ($("#assignment_name").val() == "") {
  $(".to_description").addClass("disabled");
};
```

This adds the class on load but it doesn't remove the class if someone types in the field. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `removeClass` binded to an event that triggers when user enters text, such as `keyup`, for example:

```
$("#assignment_name").on('keyup', function() {
  if ($("#assignment_name").val() == "") {
    $(".to_description").addClass("disabled");
  } else {
    $(".to_description").removeClass("disabled")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just adding the class when first loading it, besides that you need to add an "onChange" event handler to check further changes on this input.

```
if ($("#assignment_name").val() == "") {
    $(".to_description").addClass("disabled");

    $("#assignment_name").on("change", function() {
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            $(".to_description").addClass("disabled");          
        } else {
            $(".to_description").removeClass("disabled"); 
        }
    });
};
```